# If two function agree on a dense set, what condition is necessary for them to be equal?

Tags: real-analysis, dense-subspaces

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $g$ a continuous function.
If $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ in a dense set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$, does $f$ having the Darboux property imply that
$f$ and $g$ are equal on $\mathbb{R}$?

I know that if $f$ is continuous this is true, but are there any other weaker assumptions so that the statement is true (like having the Darboux property)?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Darboux isn't enough: some Darboux functions $f$ satisfy $f(I)=\Bbb R$ for any interval $I$, and thus changing any countable number of values of $f$ will not remove the Darboux property for such functions.

Answer (score 2):

For one, the Darboux property is not sufficient:

The Conway base 13 function $f$ has the Darboux property and is onto in every interval. In particular, we in each of the countably many intervals $I_n$ with rational endpoints some $\alpha_n\in I_n$ such that $f(0)=0$. Henc $f$ agrees with $g(x)=0$ on the dense set $\{\,\alpha_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\,\}$